# Parsing nested json list

Tags: python, json

I have a nested json response from a vendors API.

```
{
    "data":{
        "id":"hidden",
        "type":"file_import",
        "attributes":{
            "id":"hidden",
            "type":"Academics API",
            "dry_run":false,
            "status":"completed",
            "import_started_at":"2023-09-05T15:13:59.159Z",
            "import_completed_at":"2023-09-05T15:14:11.581Z",
            "result":{
                "info":{
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":{
                        "created":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[]
                        },
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[                               
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "courses":{
                        "created":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[]
                        },
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0,
                            "list":[                                
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "enrollments":{
                        "updated":{
                            "total":0
                        },
                        "students":{
                            "created":{
                                "total":0
                            },
                            "updated":{
                                "total":0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "warnings":{
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":[],
                    "courses":[],
                    "enrollments":[
                        {
                            "type":"duplicate_school_ids",
                            "message":"The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored",
                            "list":[
                                "12345678",
                                "87654321",
                                "11122233",
                                "44455566",
                                "77788899"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"missing_students",
                            "message":"The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.",
                            "list":[
                                "65437898",
                                "77788899"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "errors":{
                    "general":[],
                    "original_data":[],
                    "terms":[],
                    "teachers":[],
                    "courses":[],
                    "enrollments":[]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get to warnings and capture each type.  So far I'm only seeing enrollment warning such as duplicate_school_ids, and missing_students.  I'm assuming I will always have type, message, and list for each type warning, for example

```
"terms": [
            {
              "type": "missing_terms",
              "message": "The following terms were not found in the school's terms list and were ignored",
              "list": [
                "Spring 2021",
                "Spring 2022"
              ]
            }
```

The end result is to put this into an email after the process completes and send it to department staff to fix the data issues.

I'm thinking to create four empty list and populate them with what is found in the json reponse.

```
self.term_warnings: list[TermWarnings] = []
self.enrollment_warnings: list[EnrollmentWarnings] = []
self.course_warnings: list[CourseWarnings] = []
self.teacher_warning: list[TeacherWarnings] = []
```

Then check the length of each to see whether they are empty or I need to dump them into an email.

So my code is rough but look like this.

```
f = open("sample_result.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)

warnings = data["data"]["attributes"]["result"]
for w in warnings["warnings"]:
    for t in w["enrollments"]:
        for emplid in t["list"]:
            #print(f"Warning type:{t}, Student - {emplid}")
            self.enrollment_warnings.append(
                EnrollmentWarnings({t},{emplid})
```

My code doesn't work with this error.

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: read the error - which line does the problem occur on?  Step 2: understand the error - "string indices must be integers" implies that you have tried to index into a string, so it must mean that one of your places like `t["list"]` or `w["enrollments"]` etc the `t` or `w` is not a dictionary as you expect but is actually a string

Answer (score 1):

```
for w in warnings["warnings"]:
```

`warnings["warnings"]` is a dictionary.  Iterating over a dictionary gives you the *keys* of the dictionary.  So in the first iteration of the above loop, `w` is the string "terms", because that is the first *key* in the dictionary.

Then `for t in w["enrollments"]:` gives you the error, because `w` is a string.

You **already know** exactly what keys are present in the `warnings` dictionary, so you don't need to iterate over that dictionary itself.  Instead, iterate over the known sub-lists:

```
for term in warnings["terms"]:
    ...
for teacher in warnings["teachers"]:
    ...
for course in warnings["courses"]:
    ...
for enrollment in warnings["enrollments"]:
    ...
```

Comment: So how do I iterate over these lists?
 "terms":[],
 "teachers":[],
 "courses":[],
 "enrollments":[]

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the dictionary keys with `for w in warnings["warnings"]`.

Since you only want to iterate over the enrollments, you need another level of dictionary access:

```
warnings = data["data"]["attributes"]["result"]["warnings"]
for t in warnings["enrollments"]:
    for emplid in t["list"]:
        #print(f"Warning type:{t['type']}, Student - {emplid}")
        self.enrollment_warnings.append(
            EnrollmentWarnings({t},{emplid})
```

Comment: Thanks...were making some progress.  

Warning type:{'type': 'duplicate_school_ids', 'message': 'The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored', 'list': ['12345678', '87654321', '11122233', '44455566', '77788899']}, Student - 12345678
Warning type:{'type': 'missing_students', 'message': "The following Students were not found in the school's students list and were ignored.", 'list': ['65437898', '77788899']}, Student - 77788899

{t} contain far too much data.  I need to separate and capture type, messsage, and emplid so I can load them into my list.

Comment: That error is specific to your whatever library you're using to process the data, it has nothing to do with parsing the JSON.

Comment: There isn't an error.

f"Warning type:{warning_type} doesn't just give me 'duplicate_school_ids' which is what I want as well as capturing message.

It gives me {'type': 'duplicate_school_ids', 'message': 'The following school ids are connected to multiple students and were ignored', 'list': ['12345678', '87654321', '11122233', '44455566', '77788899']}

Comment: Use `{t['type']}` instead of `{t}`

Comment: Why are you using `{t}` and `{emplid}` in the arguments to `EnrollmentWarnings()`? That puts each value in a set. But you can't put a dictionary in a set.